# LinkedIn Insight TAG in wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, tags, linkedin-api

I'm needing to insert a linkedin insight tag into a landing page in wordpress.com (free account). I found many tutorials that uses header & footers plugin, but if I'm not wrong, I need to purchase a plan to be able to install plugins. Does someone know how can I insert these tags in cases like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, in WordPress.com only specific paid plans ( Business and eCommerce) allow you to install plugins.

On the other hand, multiple actions can be performed without installing any plugin. What is the goal of inserting that tag?